# Getting extra column 'require_validation' when asking for table columns

Tags: php, mysql

When using the query

```
select distinct(column_name) as column_name, data_type from information_schema.columns
where table_name='reg_add_ons' order by ordinal_position
```

I get an extra column on my dev server.  On my local server everything works fine.  This is the only table this happens on.  I have tried dropping the table and adding it again with this statement

```
delimiter $$

CREATE TABLE `reg_add_ons` (
  `add_on_id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `eventcode` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `add_on_desc` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `add_on_price` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `add_on_detail` text,
  `add_on_label` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `add_on_choices` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `image_name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `internal_only` varchar(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `assign_code` text,
  `reg_status` varchar(50) DEFAULT 'Active',
  PRIMARY KEY (`add_on_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=89 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1$$
```

I have a bit of the flu so this is not making sense to me right now.

Dev box is a Windows 7 machine running MySQL 5.6.10
Localhost is Windows 7 running MySQL 5.5.24
Production server is Linux MySQL 5.0.45

It is only this one table on this one machine (Dev) having problems.  what is the field require_validation?  Where does it come from?

Any insight is appreciated

Comment: Are you able to normalize your table? It seems like `label` and `choices` can accept more than one value.

Comment: you may have another database, try to add (and TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbname')!

Comment: @Akam I love you, worked like a charm.

Comment: Also, I was able to get rid of `distinct()` function with this change.